# Telerik TreeView | NodeExpand event is providing the wrong node value when using NodeTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, treeview, telerik

I am using  Telerik version: 2009.3.1208.0

My task is to add an arrow to the node (on the right side of the node) so people can left-click on it and access context menu.

[image]

I was able to to do that through creating a nodetemplate (subscribing to an interface) and then assigning my class to NodeTemplate property (on Page Init)

Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports Telerik.Web.UI

    Public Class MyNodeTemplate
        Implements ITemplate

        Public Sub InstantiateIn(ByVal container As Control) Implements ITemplate.InstantiateIn
            Dim newLabel As New Label()
            newLabel.CssClass = "nodeLabel"
            newLabel.Text = DirectCast(container, RadTreeNode).Text

            Dim arrowDiv As New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV")
            arrowDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "nodeRightClickArrow")
            arrowDiv.Attributes.Add("onclick", "LeftClickContextMenuClick(event, this);")

            container.Controls.Add(newLabel)
            container.Controls.Add(arrowDiv)
        End Sub

    End Class
```

Everything seems fine **EXCEPT**:

When expanding one of the nodes, the **NodeExpand Event sends the wrong value for the node that is being expanded**. For example, if I expand Node 3, it gives me value (e.Node.Value)  for Node 1. See picture below for more explanation. As a result wrong child nodes are loaded.
[image]

Questions:

1) Why NodeExpand is broken when NodeTemplate is being added ?

2) Any way to achieve  adding an arrow to the node so people can left-click on it without overwriting NodeTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the Node Click method, in node click your code

```
protected void treeView_NodeClick(object sender, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    int id;
    int.TryParse(e.Node.Value, out id);
    e.Node.Expanded = true // Expand the node manually, or IsExpanded, not remember
}
```

need to work. Aditionaly, you cold expand the node manually using. The [Telerik Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-server-node-expand.html) says that this event occurs when the node expands, so it means what happens when the node expands and i think you need you expand the node.

Comment: NodeClick is used when the item in the node is clicked up, not when someone clicks the "+" in the tree.